Polars: Replace parts of dataframe with other parts of dataframe
I'm looking for an efficient way to copy / replace parts of a dataframe with other parts of the same dataframe in Polars.
For instance, in the following minimal example dataframe
pl.DataFrame({
  "year": [2020,2021,2020,2021],
  "district_id": [1,2,1,2],
  "distribution_id": [1, 1, 2, 2],
  "var_1": [1,2,0.1,0.3],
  "var_N": [1,2,0.3,0.5],
  "unrelated_var": [0.2,0.5,0.3,0.7],
})

I'd like to replace all column values of "var_1" & "var_N" where the "distribution_id" = 2 with the corresponding values where the "distribution_id" = 1.
This is the desired result:
pl.DataFrame({
  "year": [2020,2021,2020,2021],
  "district_id": [1,2,1,2],
  "distribution_id": [1, 1, 2, 2],
  "var_1": [1,2,1,2],
  "var_N": [1,2,1,2],
  "unrelated_var": [0.2,0.5,0.3,0.7],
})

I tried to use a "when" expression, but it fails with "polars.exceptions.ShapeError: shapes of self, mask and other are not suitable for zip_with operation"
df = df.with_columns([
  pl.when(pl.col("distribution_id") == 2).then(df.filter(pl.col("distribution_id") == 1).otherwise(pl.col(col)).alias(col) for col in columns_to_copy
  ]
)

Here's what I used to do with SQLAlchemy:
table_alias = table.alias("table_alias")
stmt = table.update().\
    where(table.c.year == table_alias.c.year).\
    where(table.c.d_id == table_alias.c.d_id).\
    where(table_alias.c.distribution_id == 1).\
    where(table.c.distribution_id == 2).\
    values(var_1=table_alias.c.var_1,
           var_n=table_alias.c.var_n)

Thanks a lot for you help!

You could filter the 1 columns, change their id to 2 and discard the unneeded columns.
df.filter(distribution_id = 1).select(
   "year", "district_id", "^var_.+$", distribution_id = pl.lit(2, pl.Int64)
)

shape: (2, 5)
┌──────┬─────────────┬───────┬───────┬─────────────────┐
│ year ┆ district_id ┆ var_1 ┆ var_N ┆ distribution_id │
│ ---  ┆ ---         ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---             │
│ i64  ┆ i64         ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ i64             │
╞══════╪═════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════════════════╡
│ 2020 ┆ 1           ┆ 1.0   ┆ 1.0   ┆ 2               │
│ 2021 ┆ 2           ┆ 2.0   ┆ 2.0   ┆ 2               │
└──────┴─────────────┴───────┴───────┴─────────────────┘


(note: "^var_.+$" selects columns by regex, but selectors can be used if preferred.)

With the data "aligned", you can pass it to  .update()
df.update(
   df.filter(distribution_id = 1)
     .select("year", "district_id", "^var_.+$", distribution_id = pl.lit(2, pl.Int64)),
   on=["year", "district_id", "distribution_id"]
)

shape: (4, 6)
┌──────┬─────────────┬─────────────────┬───────┬───────┬───────────────┐
│ year ┆ district_id ┆ distribution_id ┆ var_1 ┆ var_N ┆ unrelated_var │
│ ---  ┆ ---         ┆ ---             ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---           │
│ i64  ┆ i64         ┆ i64             ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64           │
╞══════╪═════════════╪═════════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════════════╡
│ 2020 ┆ 1           ┆ 1               ┆ 1.0   ┆ 1.0   ┆ 0.2           │
│ 2021 ┆ 2           ┆ 1               ┆ 2.0   ┆ 2.0   ┆ 0.5           │
│ 2020 ┆ 1           ┆ 2               ┆ 1.0   ┆ 1.0   ┆ 0.3           │
│ 2021 ┆ 2           ┆ 2               ┆ 2.0   ┆ 2.0   ┆ 0.7           │
└──────┴─────────────┴─────────────────┴───────┴───────┴───────────────┘


Nice! I did not now about .update.

@Hericks Yeah, it's just a wrapper/helper around join() really - inspired by pandas.DataFrame.update - it's not to everybody's liking but does offer some "simpler" syntax in certain situations.

Thanks a lot for you answer! Accepted this one as it's very concise and readable!

As a more generally applicable approach (e.g. if the distribution ids to be filled / to fill with are not consecutive), we can

left-join with a filtered dataframe of the values to fill with,
use a pl.when().then().otherwise() construct to select the column value / joined column values depending on the value of distribution_id,
drop the joined column.

import polars.selectors as cs

(
    df
    .join(
        df.filter(pl.col("distribution_id") == 1),
        on=["year", "district_id"],
        how="left",
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("distribution_id") != 2).then(col).otherwise(col + "_right")
        for col in ["var_1", "var_N"]
    )
    .drop(cs.ends_with("_right"))
)

shape: (4, 6)
┌──────┬─────────────┬─────────────────┬───────┬───────┬───────────────┐
│ year ┆ district_id ┆ distribution_id ┆ var_1 ┆ var_N ┆ unrelated_var │
│ ---  ┆ ---         ┆ ---             ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---           │
│ i64  ┆ i64         ┆ i64             ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64           │
╞══════╪═════════════╪═════════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════════════╡
│ 2020 ┆ 1           ┆ 1               ┆ 1.0   ┆ 1.0   ┆ 0.2           │
│ 2021 ┆ 2           ┆ 1               ┆ 2.0   ┆ 2.0   ┆ 0.5           │
│ 2020 ┆ 1           ┆ 2               ┆ 1.0   ┆ 1.0   ┆ 0.3           │
│ 2021 ┆ 2           ┆ 2               ┆ 2.0   ┆ 2.0   ┆ 0.7           │
└──────┴─────────────┴─────────────────┴───────┴───────┴───────────────┘


In this concrete example, this can be solved with a simple pl.Expr.forward_fill after setting the var_* variables to None (which can be done with a pl.when().then() expression, missing the otherwise() term).
import polars.selectors as cs

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("distribution_id") == 1).then(cs.starts_with("var_"))
    )
    .sort("year", "district_id")
    .with_columns(
        cs.starts_with("var_").forward_fill()
    )
)

shape: (4, 6)
┌──────┬─────────────┬─────────────────┬───────┬───────┬───────────────┐
│ year ┆ district_id ┆ distribution_id ┆ var_1 ┆ var_N ┆ unrelated_var │
│ ---  ┆ ---         ┆ ---             ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---           │
│ i64  ┆ i64         ┆ i64             ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆ f64           │
╞══════╪═════════════╪═════════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════════════╡
│ 2020 ┆ 1           ┆ 1               ┆ 1.0   ┆ 1.0   ┆ 0.2           │
│ 2020 ┆ 1           ┆ 2               ┆ 1.0   ┆ 1.0   ┆ 0.3           │
│ 2021 ┆ 2           ┆ 1               ┆ 2.0   ┆ 2.0   ┆ 0.5           │
│ 2021 ┆ 2           ┆ 2               ┆ 2.0   ┆ 2.0   ┆ 0.7           │
└──────┴─────────────┴─────────────────┴───────┴───────┴───────────────┘


Here's an approach that more closely resembles what you attempted to do:
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col('distribution_id')==2)
    .then(
        pl.col('^var.*$')
        .filter(pl.col('distribution_id')==1)
        .first()
        .over('year','district_id')
        )
    .otherwise(pl.col('^var.*$'))
)

It starts off with a when because you only want to replace the values when distribution_id==2. Then it takes the column (multiple columns with regex) that you want to change it filters it by the values that you want to source from. If you just stop at the filter then you're trying to feed a column that is 4 rows long with a column that is 2 rows long which, of course, doesn't work. To make it work, you tell it that you just want the first value for each group that you care about. The group goes in over like a df.group_by.agg but over goes last in the chain. Since, presumably, year/district_id represents a unique primary key, there's only one value per group so you could just as well use first/last/max/min/etc, it just needs to be some aggregate function.

Thanks a lot for your answer, this really helped me understand why my approach failed! Accepted the other answer because the "update" approach is more concise, but again thanks for taking the time to explain!
